# volatile keyword for objects in C++

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, volatile, stdatomic

I have a thread safe counter object( it's a class which uses std::atomic load() and store() )
as one of the class members. Thread 1 increments the counter and Thread 2 reads the counter.

Usually, primitive types ( int etc ) which are shared by different threads are declared volatile to prevent any compiler optimizations. Do I have to declare this thread safe counter object which is shared by 2 different threads as volatile ?

Could someone provide more insight into this ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [volatile (C++)  msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/12a04hfd.aspx)

You don't have to because

- "The volatile keyword in C++11 ISO Standard code is to be used only for hardware access; do not use it for inter-thread communication. For inter-thread communication, use mechanisms such as std::atomic from the C++ Standard Template Library."

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no need if the object is declared atomic.

A C or C++ compiler may not reorder reads and writes to volatile memory locations, nor may it omit a read or write to a volatile memory location.

By using `atomic`, it already achieves the what `volatile` intended to do, so no need to declare `volatile`.

Comment: do u mean to say that it's sufficient if the objects implements atomic operations ?

Comment: I'm quite doubtful. I think atomic doesn't warrant prevention of compiler optimization.

Comment: @KodeWarrior do you really have any idea about atomic operation? your object is protected by mutex, how can compiler optimize away the mutex protect...

Comment: I do have a good idea of atomic operation. That's why I think your statement is wrong ! If the variable is allocated in register, even though the operation is atomic, reads/writes from another thread will not be reflect.

Comment: @KodeWorrior: std:atomic in C++ also takes away compiler optimizations, take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh874894.aspx